# Suppose $G$ is a group and $a\in G$ with $|a| = m$. Prove that $\langle a^k \rangle=\langle a \rangle \iff \gcd(k, m) = 1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group and $a\in G$ with $|a| = m$. Prove that $\langle a^k \rangle=\langle
a \rangle \iff \gcd(k, m) = 1$.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Hint: the group $\langle a\rangle$ is a cyclic group of order $m$.  Can you prove a corresponding statement for cyclic groups of order $m$?

Comment: Okay great thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

$\langle a^k\rangle = \langle a\rangle \iff a \in \langle a^k\rangle\iff \exists n\!: a^{kn}\!=a \iff\exists n\!: a^{kn-1}=1\overset{{\rm ord}\,a\, =\, m}\iff\exists n\!:\ m\mid kn\!-\!1$ $\!\iff\!$ $\exists j,n\!:\ jm+kn = 1\iff \gcd(m,k)=1\,$ by Bezout

Comment: You proof is nicely short, but I wouldn't teach math beginners this proof style. Matt's style is the way to go (it generalizes also to harder problem) at least for beginners' questions. For advanced questions style wouldn't matter so much, but equivalences might not work out anymore.

Comment: @j.p. Au contraire, I think it is essential to learn *asap* how to efficiently manipulate equivalences. You can find many examples  of such in my posts, e.g. exploiting the universal properties of gcd and lcm: $\ a\mid b,c\color{#c00}\iff a\mid (b,c),\,$ and $\, c,b\mid a\color{#c00}\iff [c,b]\mid a\ $

Comment: I like your posts about intermediate to difficult problems where an experienced mathematician (like you are) has to think a bit about a solution. There shortness is a plus. But a beginner knowing how to manipulate equivalences can prove just easy things. I think learning the proper techniques that work also for difficult problems is worth more than being able to solve a trivial problem more quickly. (Universal properties are a good thing to know about, but many - not you - on mse don't have the technique to apply them.)

Comment: @j.p. Remember that answers are not only for the OP. Many readers may be able to comprehend the answer, even if it may be beyond the level of the OP (esp. by comparing to other answers). To me, one of the unique benefits of a site like this is that one can find answers at various levels, and by interpolating the answers one can begin to learn more advanced ideas. By providing a mix of answers at various levels one increases the possibility that a reader may be able to gradually climb the learning curve.

Comment: I don't see a difference in the level of the answers for this problem, only in style. But anyway, let's agree to disagree. I'll keep liking (and upvoting) your answers to difficult problems, and disliking (but not downvoting) your answers to easy problems.

Comment: The terseness of Bill's response nearly *demands* additional thought. Such a demand yields precisely what you give it. Elegance is an aesthetic much admired by many mathematicians, and it's good to see an example of what this might actually entail. Personally I would urge the OP to "unpack" Bill's answer, as it is a good test of comprehension. Yes, there are "lines to read between"-that's sort of the point.

Answer (score 1):

If $\langle a^k\rangle=\langle a\rangle$, then there exists $n$ such that $a^{kn}=a$, so that $kn\equiv 1\pmod{m}$. Thus $k$ is invertible mod $m$, and therefore $\gcd(k,m)=1$.

Suppose conversely that $\gcd(k,m)=1$. We know that for all $n$ we have $a^{kn}\in\langle a\rangle$. Thus $\langle a^k\rangle\subseteq \langle a\rangle$. To show the opposite containment it will suffice to show that there is some $n$ such that $a^{kn}=a$. This will happen if $kn\equiv 1\pmod{m}$, and since $\gcd(k,m)=1$ there exists an $n$ making this happen. Thus the opposite containment holds.

Comment: excellent answer

Comment: @learnmore Thanks. I seem to remember this being harder but I'm probably thinking of something else involving cyclic groups.

Answer (score 1):

For another method suppose $ \langle a^k \rangle = \langle a \rangle $ and  $ d = \gcd(k, m) \gt 1 $.

Then there is $t, s \in \Bbb Z$ such that  $dt =  m$ and $ds = k$ with $t \lt m$.

Then, $ (a^k)^t = (a^{ds})^t = (a^{dt})^s = (a^m)^s = e^s = e  $. But then $ \langle a^k \rangle $ would have less then $t$ elements, hence less than $m$ elements whence $ \langle a^k \rangle \neq \langle a \rangle $ leading to a contradiction.

Hence $\gcd (k,m) = 1$.

For the other direction, suppose $k, m $ are relatively prime integers. Then there exists integers $x, y $ such that $ mx + ky  = 1$.

Then for any integer $n$ we have that $ n = nmx + nky  $. Hence, $$ a^n = (a^m)^{nx} \cdot (a^k)^{ny} = (a^k)^{ny}$$ which establishes that  $ \langle a^k \rangle \supseteq \langle a \rangle $. The other inclusion is obvious.

$\mathscr{Q.E.D.}$